# minSdkVersion 15 com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0

Tags: android, google-maps

i'm using com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0 inmy build gradle
and minSdkVersion 15  my app work's fine but in 5.0.2 android version
app refused to start

Comment: what is the error code see "Android Monitor"

Comment: unfortunately i can't test it on emulater